How can I bend the black bands inward as they reach the end of the cylinder
I have a cylinder with a wave texture that gives the bands you see. I want to be able to bend the black or white bands inward as they reach the end of the cylinder, as shown with one of the bands with the red markings in one of the screenshots.
How can I achieve this?



Use a coordinate vector that is made of:

Object X * (1 - Generated Z)
Object Y
Object Z

